# What do we hook in Drupal 6 for inbound URL rewrites?

Tags: 6, uri

Where conditional rewrite is desired, not supported by existing path modules, and where we'd prefer to stay out of .htaccess, where might we hook in Drupal 6?

Along the lines of Drupal 7 [`hook_URL_inbound_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7), I think.

Answer (score 3):

[`hook_URL_inbound_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) was introduced as part of a contributed module in Drupal 6 ([URL alter](http://drupal.org/project/url_alter)), and was moved to core with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 6, the equivalent of [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) is [custom_url_rewrite_inbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6) which is not a hook, but a function to put in the settings.php file used by Drupal.

The [URL alter](http://drupal.org/project/url_alter) module defines that function, and call any implementation of `hook_url_inbound_alter()` defined from other modules, allowing modules to use the same code for Drupal 6, and Drupal 7.

The same is true for [custom_url_rewrite_outbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite_outbound/6), and [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7).